# Can anyone explain me seaborn's set_context()?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I am trying to learn visualization with python and stuck here:

```
sns.set_context('notebook')

ax = data.plot.hist(bins=25, alpha=0.42)
ax.set_xlabel('Size (cm)');
```

Can anyone help me to explain what does this code sample mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html):

> **seaborn.set_context(context=None, font_scale=1, rc=None)**
>
> Set the
>   plotting context parameters.
>
> This affects things like the size of the labels, lines, and other
>   elements of the plot, but not the overall style. The base context is
>   “notebook”, and the other contexts are “paper”, “talk”, and “poster”,
>   which are version of the notebook parameters scaled by .8, 1.3, and
>   1.6, respectively.
>
> Parameters:    context : dict, None, or one of {paper, notebook, talk,
>   poster}
>
> A dictionary of parameters or the name of a preconfigured set.
>
> font_scale : float, optional
>
> Separate scaling factor to independently scale the size of the font
>   elements.
>
> rc : dict, optional
>
> Parameter mappings to override the values in the preset seaborn
>   context dictionaries. This only updates parameters that are considered
>   part of the context definition.

`sns.set_context('notebook')` in your example, sets up a number of parameters which will define how seaborn produces plots you generate using the module.

Comment: descriptions of the parameters inside the context can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) at Matplotlib's "Customizing Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams" page.

Comment: I had to reset context to 'paper' to get visualizations back to original context, thank you for your answer